# MYSQL - SELECT row with lowest value and other conditions, or a fallback with highest

Tags: php, mysql, join, max

there seem to be a lot of threads here asking similar questions, but I'm yet to find the one that helps me solve my problem.

I'm trying to select a row with the **lowest** value where three other conditions must be true OR fall back to another set of conditions, given a variable (`uc`) and select the highest price.

```
Table: level (sample data)
id  |price  |copies |used   |uc
--------------------------------------
1   |7      |10     |10     |charlie01
2   |17     |10     |8      |charlie01
3   |37     |5      |5      |charlie01
4   |47     |10     |9      |charlie01
7   |5      |15     |9      |charlie02
8   |15     |15     |0      |charlie02
9   |35     |15     |0      |charlie02
10  |45     |15     |0      |charlie02
11  |3      |5      |5      |charlie03
12  |13     |5      |5      |charlie03
```

Results:
**EDITED RESULTS - charlie01 should be 2**

```
VARIABLE    |RESULTING ROW
--------------------------
charlie01   |2
charlie02   |7
charlie03   |12
```

**### START Pseudocode: ###**

Select the row with the **lowest** `price` where `used` is less than `copies` and `used` is greater than `0` and `uc` equals `VARIABLE` OR IF NO RESULTS (which means all the `used` are equal to `copies`) Select the row with the highest price where `used` equals `copies` and `uc` equals `VARIABLE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM level
WHERE

    (
        used < copies
        AND used > 0
        AND uc = *VARIABLE*
    )
 ### OR IF NO RESULTS ###
    (
        used = copies
        AND uc = *VARIABLE*
    )

ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**### END Pseudocode ###**

This is the query I wrote (using `uc` `charlie01` as an example):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `level` 
    WHERE 
        ((
        `used` < `copies`
        AND `used` > '0'
        )
        OR
        (
        `used` = `copies`
        ))
        AND `uc` = 'charlie01'
        ORDER BY `price` ASC

        ) AS T
ORDER BY `used` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

It doesn't work on the sample data because of record `3`, even though `used = copies`. This is because `used on record 3 < used on record 2 (the row we want, because it has the lowest price)`

I know **MAX()** exists and have tried for the last hour to use it, but with no success, I really don't think I understand how it works, It seems to just be selecting the maximum value of the whole column no matter what...?

Now, I've gone round in circles adding conditions and such, but I think I need to do a `JOIN` of some type but I'm not really sure where to start with it. How do you think I should go about this query?

**EDIT: I'm really sorry, I just realised I was saying highest price when I was actually trying to select the lowest price where `used` < `copies` BUT the highest price if all `used` = `copies`**

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: But row 4 *is* the highest price where used < copies. Why did you change the result table?

Comment: Sh*t I'm so sorry, I just realised I was saying highest price when I was actually trying to select the lowest price where used < copies, brain lapse after playing with this for so long... :(

Comment: :) I'll change the code snippet if you change the result table

Comment: Result table is correct now, i'm definite :) Sorry again >.<

Comment: charlie03 should be 12, because all used = copies, so it should select the highest price from those rows, thanks so much for all this help by the way :)

Comment: I've withdrawn my answer, because it doesn't solve the problem, but if I can think of something that does, I'll post again.

Comment: thanks heaps for the help @wlangstroth, I'll keep working on it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're working on production code with this, i'd wait for a better answer, but a couple interesting options that might work for you...

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, (used < copies and used > 0) AS copies_avail FROM level
  ORDER BY copies_avail desc, IF(copies_avail, price, -price) ASC
) AS x GROUP BY uc;
```

(you can just use the inner section if you want to specify a uc in a where clause)

similar option that's even more interesting (trying not to say hackish =p) would be

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM level 
  ORDER BY IF(used < copies AND used > 0, price, -price + 10000) ASC
) AS x GROUP BY uc;
```

(where 10000 is much higher than any expected price in the table)

anyway... believe the output of both of these match your edited results, but are probably horrible performance wise. if you do get stuck doing something like this, you could probably store the copies_avail query result in the table to avoid the filesort?

also, curious about the case where used = 0 and copies > 0 - couldn't tell from your description if it should be sorted with the price asc or price desc group. in these examples, it's with price desc.

Comment: Thanks for that, both querys work exactly as I need :) Could you possibly elaborate on the part about storing copies_avail? Do you mean store a flag (1|0) to avoid sorting everything? What would be the best way implement this?

Comment: Hey Charlie, was thinking that storing the `(used < copies AND used > 0)` logic in the db may save some complexity in the query, but actually not sure since we also use price on the order by.